# Chrome extension background service worker script download file from blob

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, blob, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm using **manifest v3**. I've a fetched file and converted it to a blob in the background script and I want to download it, I know the standard `URL.createObjectURL` but this would not work as `window.URL.createObjectURL` isn't available to the **background service worker** and so obviously libraries like `FileSaver.saveAs` won't work which relies on the same.

My code currently looks something like this (oversimplified):-

```
im = await fetch('https://url.com/img.png', {method:"GET", headers:headers})
bl = await im.blob()
download(bl)
```

I want to write a function `download(blobObj)` that'll download the blob. I'm aware of `chrome.downloads.download(url, filename)` which directly downloads the file from URL but I can't use it in the original code because there are a few more other things going on too so, I need a function that is capable of downloading the file from a blob that is passed to it as an argument.

Thank you

Comment: Some further info that perhaps might help you: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/u0NH7L3v9L4